# Block a specific URL, not all domain

Tags: internet

As the title says, Is there a way to block a specific URL and not the whole domain?
Let's say I want to block Google Images(google.com/imghp) but not Google (google.com) or block Facebook Groups (facebook.com/groups/) but not Facebook (facebook.com).
I have tried with OpenDNS and the host file but can't still find a solution to this.

Comment: I can only imagine ways do this in the browser or using a proxy server... using dns is not going to work.

Comment: @JavierRivera How could I do this with a proxy server?

Comment: Se Matt Caswell answer, Dansguardian is a proxy already configured for web filtering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using Dansguardian?

Info [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DansGuardian) and [here](http://dansguardian.org/)